# Do we need to remove some charaters from SUBSTRING length if start is not from 0?

Tags: sql-server

What's the difference between below two statements. Both return the same output "is a sentence"

```
DECLARE @MyStr nvarchar(max) = 'This is a sentence'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@MyStr, 6, LEN(@MyStr)-5)
```

and

```
DECLARE @MyStr nvarchar(max) = 'This is a sentence'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@MyStr, 6, LEN(@MyStr))
```

I ran both and the latter doesn't add any spaces or anything.

Comment: the `**-5**` causes syntax error, what result do you expect to get using that?

Comment: @RicardoPontual He is just trying to highlight the `-5` in `LEN(@MyStr) - 5`, I think.

Comment: @SunMan what are you trying to achieve exactly ?

Comment: @iSR5 I am just trying to learn from the code written by someone else (an expert). Why someone put an extra efforts of making calculation in this code is interesting to me. It was clearly on purpose and I want to learn why from experts here as it makes me a better programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter to `SUBSTRING` is the length of substring to take.  In the first example, the length covers exactly the remainder of the string.  In the second example, the length *exceeds* the actual available length of the string, by 5 characters.  Regarding what happens when the length is *greater* than the available length, we can turn to the [documentation for SUBSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> **length**
>   Is a positive integer or bigint expression that specifies how many characters of the expression will be returned. If length is negative, an error is generated and the statement is terminated. **If the sum of start and length is greater than the number of characters in expression, the whole value expression beginning at start is returned.**

In other words, if the `length` parameter plus the start passed is greater than what is available, then `SUBSTRING` just returns as much as is available.

Comment: so I am not wasting any memory if I don't specify -5 because that's an extra work of calculation to find 'length' to make sure it touches exactly the last letter? or a performance impact may be?

Comment: @SunMan I don't know for certain without seeing the source code for `SUBSTRING`, but performance should not be an issue here.